Incorrect user access token being sent for configured HTTP client in UserDuende.AccessTokenManagement
Our ASP .Net Core 8 site uses http clients configured with the 'AddUserAccessTokenHttpClient' functionality of Duende.AccessTokenManagement to automatically attach (and renew, if necessary) bearer access tokens for HTTP requests made to our API.  We're noticing, however, that if multiple users are using the site at the same time, the tokens being attached to a user's request are sometimes from an entirely different user, resulting in the API responding as if the request was coming from the other user.  We haven't quite been able to pin down the scenario in which this occurs, however it definitely requires multiple users to be using the site at the same time.  I'm able to debug the Duende code and can follow the execution down to where the saved access tokens are retrieved from the session, but without a reliable way to reproduce the issue yet I'm just trying to understand what might contribute to something like this happening.
Some things of note which might be important:

We are using Identity Server for authentication via OpenID Connect
We are using a custom Session Store to store our application cookie in a distributed SQL Server cache

Here are the relevant sections of Startup.cs:
services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = "My-Connection-String"
    options.SchemaName = "dbo";
    options.TableName = "MyCacheTable";
});

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
});

services.Configure<DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TimeoutMinutes = 60 * 24 * 30;
});
services.AddSingleton<ITicketStore, DistributedCacheTicketStore>();

services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>("Application").Configure<IServiceProvider>((options, serviceProvider) =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    options.Cookie.Name = "mvccookie." + Environment.EnvironmentName;
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
    options.SessionStore = serviceProvider.GetService<ITicketStore>();
    options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
    options.Events.OnSigningOut = async e =>
    {
        await e.HttpContext.RevokeRefreshTokenAsync();
    };
});

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme 
        = options.DefaultSignInScheme
        = options.DefaultScheme
        = "Application";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("Application")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Identity Server", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Application";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.UsePkce = true;

        options.Authority = "My Identity Server Url";
        options.ClientId = "My Client Id";
        options.ClientSecret = "My Client Secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";
        Array.ForEach("openid profile email roles offline_access".Split(' '), options.Scope.Add);

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role",
            ValidAudience = "MyApp",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidIssuer = "My Identity Server Url",
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            AuthenticationType = "Application"
        };
    })
    ;

// adds user and client access token management
services.AddOpenIdConnectAccessTokenManagement(options =>
{
    // client config is inferred from OpenID Connect settings
    // if you want to specify scopes explicitly, do it here, otherwise the scope parameter will not be sent
    options.RefreshBeforeExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
})
;

// registers HTTP clients that uses the managed user access token
services.AddUserAccessTokenHttpClient("MyApiClient", configureClient: client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myapi.com/");
});

And the implementation of the TicketStore:
public class DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions
{
    public double TimeoutMinutes { get; set; }
}

public class DistributedCacheTicketStore : ITicketStore
{
    private const string _keyPrefix = "AuthSessionStore-";
    private readonly DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions _options;
    private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;
    private readonly TicketSerializer _ticketSerializer = TicketSerializer.Default;
    private readonly ILogger<DistributedCacheTicketStore> _logger;

    public DistributedCacheTicketStore(
        IOptions<DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions> options,
        IDistributedCache distributedCache,
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        ILogger<DistributedCacheTicketStore> logger)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
        _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(this.GetType().FullName);
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var key = $"{_keyPrefix}{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}";
        await RenewAsync(key, ticket);
        return key;
    }

    public async Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ticket));
        }
        // NOTE: Using `services.enableImmediateLogout();` will cause this method to be called per each request.

        var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions();

        var expiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
        if (expiresUtc.HasValue)
        {
            options.SetAbsoluteExpiration(expiresUtc.Value);
        }

        if (ticket.Properties.AllowRefresh ?? false)
        {
            options.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_options.TimeoutMinutes));
        }

        await _distributedCache.SetAsync(key, _ticketSerializer.Serialize(ticket), options);

        return;
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
    {
        var value = await _distributedCache.GetAsync(key);
        var ticket = value != null ? _ticketSerializer.Deserialize(value) : null;
        return ticket;
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(key);

        return;
    }
}

Thanks!
